# Pandas: Change column based on its value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When `cluster_name` contains "demo", I want to change it to "unknown".

This is the best I've managed:

```
df["cluster_name"] = "unknown" if "demo" is in df["cluster_name"] else df["cluster_name"]
```

But getting:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df["cluster_name"] = np.where(df["cluster_name"].str.contains("demo"), "unknown", df["cluster_name"])
```

See below example:

```
In [814]: df1
Out[814]: 
        State  Year  Incident  new     nn
0           a  1980       513    1    0.0
1  demo is in  1981       453    0    1.0
2           b  1982       424    1  100.0
3     my demo  1983       372  100    NaN

In [816]: df1.State = np.where(df1.State.str.contains('demo'), 'unknown', df1.State)

In [817]: df1
Out[817]: 
     State  Year  Incident  new     nn
0        a  1980       513    1    0.0
1  unknown  1981       453    0    1.0
2        b  1982       424    1  100.0
3  unknown  1983       372  100    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) if you don't need to search for the substring 'demo'. 'Contains' is ambiguous.

```
df['cluster_name'] = df['cluster_name'].replace('demo','unknown')
```

Or replace `inplace`

```
df['cluster_name'].replace('demo','unknown', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a `lambda` function, which is syntactically similar to what you were trying to do:

**Simple `map` solution**:

```
#replaces the row with 'unknown' if it is 'demo'
df['cluster_name'] = df['cluster_name'].map(lambda x : 'unknown' if x=='demo' else x)
```

**More generalized `map` solution**:

```
#replaces the row with 'unknown' if contains 'demo'
df['cluster_name'] = df['cluster_name'].map(lambda x : 'unknown' if 'demo' in x else x)
```

**Examples**:

```
>>> #simple map solution
>>> df
  cluster_name
0         demo
1         demo
2            1

>>> df['cluster_name'] = df['cluster_name'].map(lambda x : 'unknown' if x=='demo' else x)
>>> df
  cluster_name
0      unknown
1      unknown
2            1

>>> #More generalized  map solution:
>>> df1
  cluster_name
0    demo is a
1         demo
2            1
>>> df1['cluster_name'] = df1['cluster_name'].map(lambda x : 'unknown' if 'demo' in x else x)
>>> df1
  cluster_name
0      unknown
1      unknown
2            1
```